# How to grep only defined values from perl array

Tags: perl

I have a lot of arrays that have some defined array elements, and then some undefined elements.

This problem does not show in simple cases like this:

```
my @x = sort {$a <=> $b} grep {defined} @{ $args{data} };
```

but this is allowing undefined values to get through in complex cases like this:

```
sub boxplot_series {
    my %args = (
        output_type => 'eps', @_ # defaults
    );
    my @labels = sort keys %{ $args{data} };# $args{data} should be a hash of arrays
    my ($data_fh, $data_filename) = tempfile(UNLINK => 1);
    my $x = 1;
    foreach my $set (@labels) {
        my $n = scalar @{ $args{data}{$set} };
        if ($n == 0) {
           confess "$set has no values.\n";
        }
        my @x = sort {$a <=> $b} grep {defined $_} @{ $args{data}{$set} };
        if (grep undef @x) {
            confess "\@x has undef.";
        }
        if (scalar @x == 0) { next }
        my $n4 = floor(($n+3)/2)/2;
        my @d = (1, $n4, ($n +1)/2, $n+1-$n4, $n);#d <- c(1, n4, (n + 1)/2, n + 1 - n4, n)
        my @sum_array = $x;
        $x++;
        foreach my $e (0..4) {
           my $floor = floor($d[$e]-1);
           my $ceil  =  ceil($d[$e]-1);
# undef values can get through here too
           push @sum_array, (0.5 * ($x[$floor] + $x[$ceil]));
        }
        ....
```

How can I grep only defined elements from Perl arrays?

Comment: Your code works for me, no undefined values left in `@x`. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to show your entire program that shows this behavior.  Also, try it without the `sort {$a <=> $b}` to minimize the amount of code that code be wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry to waste everyone's time.  The error was elsewhere in the code, but I cannot close or delete my question now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there was a mistake in the question

Comment: `if (grep undef @x)`? Did you mean `grep ! defined, @x`?

Comment: Always create complete, minimal programs that demonstrate the problem. That process often leads the to problem, or ruling out possible problems.

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my %args = (data => [4, 2, undef, 3, undef, 1]);

my @x = sort {$a <=> $b} grep {defined} @{ $args{data} };

say for @x;
```

**But** it breaks if you specify

```
my $a;
```

before the `sort` in the same scope. That's because `$a` (and `$b`) are special global variables and you shouldn't redeclare them. Now you know why.

With [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) on, you also get

```
"my $a" used in sort comparison at ...
```

Comment: The `$a` would affect the sort, but OP said "this is allowing undefined values to get through".

Comment: @AndyLester: Hm, but it produces the `Use of uninitialized value $a in numeric comparison (<=>)` warnings which *might* lead someone to think there are uninitialized values in the comparison.

Comment: Oooh, that could be.